HTTP server performance
Why exactly does the first implementation of a basic single threaded blocking HTTP server have a much lower Requests Per Second than the second implementation? Why does it have so many Read Errors?
I'm testing this via wrk with these parameters:
wrk -t4 -c100 -d10s http://localhost:8080
Also, I am curious, where can I learn more about socket networking and HTTP and increasing performance? I have little ideas in mind about making it non-blocking and using features like select() or epoll(), and then possibly making it multi-threaded.
But please, point me to some good resources on learning about TCP sockets and building HTTP servers, and how I can increase throughput and performance. Particularly in Java would be nice.
My current diagnosis on this is possible keep alive connections, but I don't know too much about it.
First Implementation:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SimpleHttpServer {
  private static final byte[] RESPONSE = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
      "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
      "Content-Length: 12\r\n" +
      "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
      "\r\n" +
      "Hello World!").getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int port = 8080;
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
      System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port);

      while (true) {
        try (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) {
          handleClient(clientSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("Error accepting client connection: " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static void handleClient(Socket clientSocket) {
    try (InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream()) {

      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
      int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);

      out.write(RESPONSE);
      out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Error handling client: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}

Running 10s test @ http://localhost:8080
  4 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     3.23ms    5.33ms 112.16ms   99.63%
    Req/Sec     2.65k     1.12k    3.66k    84.62%
  13852 requests in 10.08s, 1.33MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 16674, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:   1373.97
Transfer/sec:    135.52KB

Second Implementation:
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SimpleHttpServer {
  private static final byte[] RESPONSE = ("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
      "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
      "Content-Length: 12\r\n" +
      "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
      "\r\n" +
      "Hello World!").getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int port = 8080;
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
      System.out.println("Server listening on port " + port);

      while (true) {
        try (Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept()) {
          handleClient(clientSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("Error accepting client connection: " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static void handleClient(Socket clientSocket) {
    try (InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream()) {

      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
      int bytesRead;

      while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(RESPONSE);
        out.flush();
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Error handling client: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}

Running 10s test @ http://localhost:8080
  4 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    24.20us   13.95us   5.83ms   97.12%
    Req/Sec    39.67k     2.53k   43.48k    69.31%
  398573 requests in 10.10s, 38.39MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 83, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:  39457.15
Transfer/sec:      3.80MB

I tried learning more about the HTTP protocol and keep alive.

If the code works and you just want to improve it, consider asking on CodeReview instead. And asking for tutorials and external resources is off-topic for StackOverflow.

That being said, I would imagine HTTP keepalives to be a big factor in your performance issue, since your 1st implementation is closing the TCP connection after every response (it should be sending Connection: close instead of Connection: keep-alive), whereas your 2nd implementation is not. HTTP keepalives were invented to help improve performance when a client sends multiple requests to the same server in a short period of time. TCP connections take time to open, and TLS sessions take time to establish, so HTTP/1.1 implementations prefer to reuse them when possible.

Thanks Remy. It was the Keep-Alive connections as you mentioned. It is the standard for HTTP 1.1 by default which I should not have overlooked. I experimented with closed and open. Now Im getting: 5,282,942 requests in 10.10s, 398.02MB read and 0 errors. Now with the proper implementation, do you have any performance suggestions?

"do you have any performance suggestions?" - StackOverflow is not the place for that kind of discussion.

Asking for off-site learning resources is explicitly off-topic here.
